# Functor that preserve finite products is natural isomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

During a lesson we proved that a functor $F:A\text{-Mod} \rightarrow\text{Set}$, where $A$ is a Commutative unital ring, and which preserves finite products -- in the sense that

- it maps the terminal element $0$  to the terminal element $\{*\}$,
- for each $M,N$ in $A\text{-Mod}$ there exist a map $\varphi_{M,N}: F(M \oplus N) \rightarrow F(M) \times F(N)$ which is an isomorphism in Set

factorizes over $\text{Ab}$, in the sense that $F(M)$ has a natural abelian sum induced over it for each $M$.

Now, the proof is clear to me, but it assumes that the isomorphism $\varphi_{M,N}$ is natural in $M$ and $N$, while asking to prove it as an exercise.

I tried to prove it using the universal property of the product in Set, but I can't find a reason why the induced map, let's call it $\psi : F(M\oplus N) \rightarrow F(M) \times F(N)$ should be exactly $\varphi$. I'll explain this better:

(sorry for the quality of the diagram but this site doesn't seem to handle diagonal arrows well)

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    F(M)    @<{\pi_{F(M)}}<<   F(M)\times F(N)     @>{\pi_{F(N)}}>>     F(N) \\
    @|                              @A{\exists!}AA                      @|   \\
    F(M)    @<{F(\pi_M)}<<     F(M\oplus N)       @>{F(\pi_N)}>>       F(N)
\end{CD}$$

This is the diagram that I expect should generate $\varphi$ and it indeed would imply its naturality. The problem is that I don't know yet that $\varphi$ is natural, thus that it is the map that makes the diagram commute, and if I forget about $\varphi$ and call this map $\psi$, I can't find a reason why it should necessarily be an isomorphism. I tried to define an inverse map but I wasn't very successful, and even in that case I couldn't seem to find a reason why the composition of the two maps would be the identity and not an automorphism.

EDIT: In a lapsus I wrote $\otimes$ instead of $\oplus$, needless to say that the result did not make sense. I now corrected it.

Comment: Just to clarify, does $\otimes$ here mean Cartesian product? Or tensor product (over $A$ I guess)? If the latter, then the unit object ($A$) of the tensor product should be mapped to the terminal object in $Set$.

Comment: I’m thinking it’s an erroneously rotated $\oplus$...

Comment: Yes, I'm really sorry, I corrected it, it was a lapsus.

Comment: That's a terrible definition of preserving finite products. The correct (and the usual) definition is precisely with the map $F(M\oplus N)\to F(M)\times F(N)$ you defined : this always exists (for any functor $F$), and we say that $F$ preserves finite products if this map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Without requiring naturality,, you lose pretty much everything; you could define $F$ to be constant with value any infinite set

Comment: I had the suspect that naturality was not implied if not explicitly required. Anyway, your counterexample doesn't map $0$ in $\{*\}$, but if we defined, for example, that F maps everything to $\mathbb{N}$ but $0$, which is mapped in the singleton it should still work. Am I wrong?

Edit: wait, if it's constant it's trivially natural.

Comment: The first sentence should be rewritten. I had to look at the original question prior to any edit in order to understand it.

Comment: Sorry, It was (I think) an edit from a moderator or something similar, and I didn't notice that they messed up a bit and put together two different things, which made the statement unclear. It should be more understandable now.

Comment: You're right, my counterexample doesn't work. It's still the case that you need to require naturality. For a better counterexample, let $A$ be an infinite field, and let $F$ be the functor that maps a vector space $V$ to the underlying set of $V^{\otimes 2}$. Since any nonzero $A$-vector space is infinite, we can do the same trick as in my wrong counterexample, but this time $0$ is mapped to $\{*\}$. And of course, it does not preserve products

Comment: Even requiring the naturality of $$ is insufficient, we need that $$ is the canonical map. There may be a counter example with $$ natural but not the canonical map, but I don't think it is really interesting relatively to the difficulty of finding it.

Comment: @Idéophage Actually, it is enough to have a natural isomorphism. Briefly, if you have $F(A \times B) \cong F A \times F B$ naturally in $(A, B)$, then it is obvious that $F$ preserves $1$; but then by considering the morphisms $\mathrm{id}_A \times {!} : A \times B \to A \times 1$ and ${!} \times \mathrm{id}_{B} : A \times B \to 1 \times B$ we obtain (possibly non-trivial) automorphisms $\lambda_A : F A \to F A$ and $\rho_B : F B \to F B$ such that composing with the automorphism $\lambda_A \times \rho_B$ yields the _canonical_ $F (A \times B) \to F A \times F B$.

Comment: Hi @ZhenLin and thank you. I had to work a bit to understand but I see now. The only problem I have is why is it obvious that $F$ preserves $1$, can you explain?

Comment: ($F(A×B)≅F(A)×F(B)$ does not imply that $F(1)=1$ in full generality.)

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused myself. If $F 1 \cong 1$ then the canonical morphism is an isomorphism – that really is obvious. But otherwise we may indeed only have $F (A \times B) \cong F A \times F B$. (Take a functor $F$ that preserves binary products and an object in the codomain category such that $X \cong X \times X$; then define a new functor $F'$ by $F' (A) = F A \times X$. This will have a natural isomorphism $F' (A \times B) \cong F' A \times F' B$.)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi In case you didn't see the remark of Zhen Lin.